# python: save list to a file with performance in mind

Tags: python

let say we have a list of strings which is so big that if I save it as a normal text file(every element in a separate line) it'll be 1GB in size;

currently I use this code to save the list:

```
savefile = codecs.open("BigList.txt", "w", "utf-8")
savefile.write("\r\n".join(BigList));
savefile.close()
```

as soon as we reach to this part of code: `"\r\n".join(BigList)`, I can see a huge bump in memory usage and also considerable time(~1min) to save the results;

any tip or suggestion for better handling this list(less memory-usage) and save it on hard-disk more quickly?

Comment: Is it the filesize or memory-usage you're mainly interested in conserving? There's always a trade-off in one of the following: CPU, Memory, Disk

Comment: memory-usage; what is important is: using less memory-usage and save on hard-disk as fast as possible;

Comment: You shouldn't be using `"\r\n"` at all but `"\n"` (which will be translated to `"\r\n"` on saving the file, since you've opened it in text mode). Right now, you're getting `"\r\r\n"` in your file...

Comment: @TimPietzcker: `codecs.open` always opens in binary mode, whether on [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) or [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.open).

Comment: @user2357112: Oh, I overlooked the `codecs.` part. Of course!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The join in:

```
"\r\n".join(BigList)
```

is creating a very large string in the memory before writing it down. It will be much more memory efficient if you use a for loop:

```
for line in BigList:
   savefile.write(line + "\r\n")
```

another question is, why do you have so many strings in the memory in the first place?

Comment: I'm reading a very big text file and add some strings to every line of it while working with the file as a list

Comment: it may be possible to work with fixed sized group of lines perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

To save disk-space you could do:

```
from gzip impo GzipFile
with GzipFile('dump.txt', 'w') as fh:
    fh.write('\r\n'.join(BigList))
```

(also use the `with` operator instead).
Combine this with a `for` operator in order to save memory:

```
from gzip impo GzipFile
with GzipFile('dump.txt', 'w') as fh:
    for item in BigList:
        fh.write(str(item)+'\r\n')
```

And to do it really quick you could potentially do (**saves memory, disk-space and time**):

```
import pickle
from gzip import GzipFile

with GzipFile('dump.pckl', 'wb') as fh:
    pickle.dump(BigList, fh)
```

Note however that this big list of yours would only be accessible to external programs if they understand pythons pickle structure on the data.
But assuming you want to re-use the BigList in your own application, pickle is the way to go.

Noticed some comment about you reading a big textfile in order to write to another file..
In that case the above an approach that would work for you.
If you want to save memory or time over two files. Consider the following instead:

```
with open('file_one.txt', 'rb') as inp:
    with open('file_two.txt', 'wb' out:
        for line in inp:
            out.write(do_work(line)+b'\r\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for line in BigList:
    savefile.write(line+'\n')
```

I would do it by iterating.